# Concatenating a tuple of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a `tupple` which contains multiple `dict`s where each `dict` contains a list as such:

```
({'num' : [1, 2, 3], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, 
 {'num' : [4, 5, 6], 'let': ['d', 'e', 'f']}, 
 {'num' : [7, 8, 9], 'let': ['g', 'h', 'i']})
```

I want to concatenate all of the `dict`s together into a single `dict` with one long list of the values from the previous `dict`s as such:

```
{'let': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
 'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

So far everything I have tried has either given me an error or resulted in the output having a `list` of `list`s rather than a single list.

Comment: You should *show* what you tried.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is a bunch of code that doesn't work necessary to understand the problem and solution?  If this was homework and I needed to show my work I would understand, but the point of the site is for people with similar problems to be able to look up questions and find answers.  I felt synthesizing my much more specific problem to a generalized, reproducible one was more in the spirit of the site rather than a code dump of things I had tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple loops through dicts, keys and `.extend`  ??

```
td = ({'num' : [1, 2, 3], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, 
 {'num' : [4, 5, 6], 'let': ['d', 'e', 'f']}, 
 {'num' : [7, 8, 9], 'let': ['g', 'h', 'i']})

d = td[0]
for e in td[1:]:
    for k, v in e.items():
        d[k].extend(v)
d
Out[42]: 
{'let': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'],
 'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just got used to `R` where looping through things like that would be extremely inefficient and there are a bunch of functions which exist to speed up run times on these kind of operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d= defaultdict(list)
s = ({'num' : [1, 2, 3], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, 
  {'num' : [4, 5, 6], 'let': ['d', 'e', 'f']}, 
  {'num' : [7, 8, 9], 'let': ['g', 'h', 'i']})
for i in s:
   d['num'].extend(i['num'])
   d['let'].extend(i['let'])
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']}
```

Or, without `defaultdict`:

```
s = ({'num' : [1, 2, 3], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c']}, 
 {'num' : [4, 5, 6], 'let': ['d', 'e', 'f']}, 
 {'num' : [7, 8, 9], 'let': ['g', 'h', 'i']})
new_s = {"num" if all(isinstance(d, int) for d in a) else "let":a for a in [reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, c) for c in zip(*[[b[-1] for b in i.items()] for i in s])]}
```

Output:

```
{'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']}
```

Comment: Is the purpose of `defaultdict` in the first answer to just make an empty dict that you can assign keys to?  If so, what is the benefit of doing this compared to initializing `d` using `s[0]` and then looping over `s[1:]`?

Comment: @Barker a `defaultdict` creates an empty dictionary; however, it is implemented such that if a value is added, appended, extended, etc. to a non-existent key in the dictionary, it will create the key set to `0`, an empty list, or a dictionary depending on the operation. The benefit of a `defaultdict` is that it allows you to not check if the key at every iteration exists in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your keys are always the same you could iterate on the keys of th first dict, and build your merged dict by chaining the lists together:

```
import itertools

d = ({'num' : [1, 2, 3], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c']},
 {'num' : [4, 5, 6], 'let': ['d', 'e', 'f']},
 {'num' : [7, 8, 9], 'let': ['g', 'h', 'i']})

r = {k:list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sd[k] for sd in d)) for k in d[0]}
```

result:

```
{'num': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'let': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']}
```